# linked list inheritance java

Tags: java, inheritance, linked-list

```
public class Link {
       public static Link LAST = new Link(-1);
       public Link next;
       public int myId;
       public Link() {
              this(10);
}
       public Link(Link next) {
              this(20);
              this.next = next;
}
      protected Link(boolean b) {
              this(99);
}
      private Link(int myId) {
              this.myId = myId;
}
@Override
      public String toString() {
             return "Link #" + myId;
}
}
       public class DataLink<T> extends Link {
       private T value;
       public DataLink(T value) {
              this(value, new Link(false));
}
       public DataLink(T value, Link parent) {
               super(parent);
               this.value = value;
}
      @Override
      public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " (" + value.toString() +")";
}
}
       public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
************************
}
}
```

By replacing the line ************************ with

**System.out.println(new DataLink<>(new Link()).next);**

it prints **Link # 99**, How does it reach **protected Link(Boolean b)**?

Comment: I'm not understanding your confusion. If `DataLink` and `Link` are in the same package, `DataLink` will have access to protected members in `Link`. Your result makes sense. You call `new Link(false)`, which triggers the boolean constructor.

Comment: it suppose to reach `public Link(Link next)` and not `protected Link (boolean b)`, by the constructor , doesn't it?

Comment: But `System.out.println(new DataLink<>(new Link()).next); ` means `(new DataLink<>(new Link())` calls `DataLink(T value)`, since `new Link` returns a value, but there is also `.next` doesn't it `null`?

Comment: `DataLink(T)` is called, which calls `DataLink(T, Link)` via `this(value, new Link(false))`. `DataLink(T, Link)` passes the `new Link(false)` that has the ID `99` to `Link(Link)` via `super(parent)` and is stored in `next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any JAVA IDE to trace the steps

```
new DataLink<>(new Link()).next
```

is getting the NEXT LINK object of the DataLink's parent class (***Link***) because DataLink class doesn't have next object.

this is the steps

```
1.new DataLink<>(new Link())
2.this(value, new Link(false));  
    3.protected Link(boolean b) {    //from new Link(false)
          this(99); 
    4. this.myId = myId;  // myId = 99, from this(99)
5.super(parent); //calling public Link(Link next)
6.this.next = next; //next = link object with myId=99
```

so when you call ***new DataLink<>(new Link()).next***, ***.next*** will call the ***next*** object in parent class which will print **Link # 99**

Comment: Why next is the object with myId=99? Doesn't it the one before, this.myId?

Comment: the "parent" object's myId = 99. super(parent) calling public Link(Link next) which assigning next is the parent

Comment: Why `public DataLink(T value, Link parent)` is called? There aren't 2 parameters..

Comment: it is from this(value, new Link(false))